# how to show attribute name and datatype on entity properties power desinger

Tags: entity, hide, show, powerdesigner

I design schema but name and datatype on entity properties are hiding. How do I show it. Please view image https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KXEd.png

Comment: Dong, you have several questions where you appear to have received a useful answer, but have not replied or voted/accepted the question. Was the answer from Pascal below of assistance?

Answer (score 1):

I guess they were hidden by resizing them to zero on the list header.

Anyway...

- you can use the [Customize Columns and Filter](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38093.1610/doc/html/rad1232023904757.html) button [image: customize button] on the
  toolbar,
- unselect Name & Code,
- validate the `Customize Columns and Filter` dialog by `[OK]`,
- go back to `Customize Columns and Filter`,
- select back Name & Code,
- validate by `[OK]`,

and the columns should come back with a default size.